# Does every first countable Lindelöf space have countable spread?

Tags: general-topology

Does every first countable Lindelöf space have countable spread?

What's meaning of countable spread? see the definition of $s(X)$

> $$s(X)=\sup\{|Y|:Y\subseteq X \text{ with the subspace topology is discrete}\}+\aleph_0.$$

Countable spread means that $s(X) = \aleph_0$.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be the [lexicographically ordered square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order_topology_on_the_unit_square); then $X$ is compact and first countable, but $s(X)=c(X)=2^\omega$.